# iOS Image Animation

Tags: ios, iphone, image

I want to show an image of glass getting filled with water in iPhone using iOS 8. I can get a white background image of glass (that shows empty glass) and water color could be light grey, for example.

- Is there an option to fill background color of glass (in intervals)
  so that it looks as if the glass is really getting filled with water?
- Can I draw complete image (glass already filled with water) part by
  part from bottom to top to show similar effect?

**Any options to display/animate such an image?**

Comment: Do you have some images for the water, or do you want to display it programmatically ?

Comment: I don't have any image for the water, but would like to use color (gray, for example) to depict water. I would prefer it done through code

Comment: I made a sample project where I animated a thermometer through code : (even the glass), maybe you can find some inspiration from it : https://github.com/micazeve/MAThermometer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `UIImageView` you can do like that, create an images for each frame:

```
images = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"]];
[imageView setAnimationImages:testArray] ;
imageView.animationDuration = 0.5;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[imageView startAnimating];
```

Another way is to have `UIView's`/`UIImageView's` composition, e.g. `UIImageView` in front, use it as mask, another one in a back, and just use simple `UIView` animation.

But anyway, such a animation can be done in many ways, depends on your needs and how nice this animation should be.

Comment: I read about stacking images for animation, but wouldn't that introduce time lag when animating images. I just want the user to see glass filling with water and not the entire image flipping every time. If I use UIView animation, would it also introduce time lag. I mean, would the user come to know that it's image being flipped?

Comment: UIView animations shouldn't introduce lag, anyway, if you want to have it animated, you need to do it with an animation. I would suggest you firstly don't care about lag, just do it :)

Comment: I did use your code along with other things and it did work for the first time. However, when I tried to integrate it with LaunchScreen, it stopped working